# How does a return statement work after a finally block in java?

Tags: java

Here's an example from the book "Java All-in-one desk reference"

```
public class CrazyWithZeros {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int answer = divideTheseNumbers(5, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Tried twice, still didn't work!");
    }
}

public static int divideTheseNumbers(int a, int b) throws Exception {

    int c;
    try {
        c = a / b;
        System.out.println("It worked!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Didn't work the first time.");
        c = a / b;
        System.out.println("It worked the second time!");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Better clean up my mess.");
    }
    System.out.println("It worked after all.");
    return c;

}
```

}

After the finally clause executes, the ArithmeticException is thrown back up to the calling method. The statement `System.out.println("It worked after all.");`would never be executed in this case. But what happened to the `return c;`?

I wonder whether the return statement would still return the result of the division or not?

========

I tried to replace "`System.out.println("Better clean up my mess.");`" with "`System.out.println(c);`", then it's compiled and the results are as follows:

> ```
> Didn't work the first time.  
> 0 
> Tried twice, still didn't work!
> ```

I can't believe the variable `c` could be calculated. (it's the wrong number, though) Why could this happen?

Then I also tried to replace "`System.out.println("Better clean up my mess.");`" with "`return c;`" and deleted the statements below the finally block, it's compiled again...Since the finally block is executed whether or not any exceptions are thrown by the try block or caught by any catch blocks, the return c; should be executed. But here're the results:

> Didn't work the first time.

looks like `c` couldn't get returned...

Comment: Try System.out.println(c); , to debug.

Comment: Computers are predictable machines. But really, they are just powerful calculators. What would happen if you tried the same division on a pocket calculator? The same thing. Otherwise calculators would be worthless, you can't trust them. So if something doesn't work, don't just try again, try to understand why the division failed. Probably you divided by zero... Also, catching "Exception" instead of "AMoreSpecificException" is a crime and should not be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect performing an error-prone operation the second time? :)

It is gonna generate an exception of the same type you came in the `catch` block with, but at that time it would not be handled - you don't have another `try-catch` within *this* `catch` block.

The `finally` is executed always regardless either an exception occurs or a normal process flow proceeds. In your case, you come to the `finally` block with the exception and throw it to the caller (`main`) where it gets handled by its own `catch` block.

> I wonder whether the return statement would still return the result of the division or not?

What do you want to return? You haven't initialized the variable `c` and there is no correct record to this variable. Therefore, Java doesn't allow to write "something unexpected or unpredictable" into the `c`.

Comment: It's a contrived example in my reference book that demonstrates how to use the finally clause. But I'm confused about whether the return statement would still work well right after that finally block, since the ArithmeticException is caught by the catch block in the main method...

Comment: @syurazetu, Cleaning up doesn't mean returning to a normal state. A `finally` block just guarantees that it will be executed regardless of the events happened before. If you come to a `finally` block with an exception, you will come out with that exception.

Comment: c is a local variabel and, I think it's initialized by "c=a/b" in the try statement.

Comment: @syurazetu, it is true, but it will be initialized **after** the expression `a/b` is evaluated and the result of this expression is calculated. Obviously, the result can't be calculated - the exception occurs

Comment: @ Andrew Tobilko , It makes sense now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

return c is not executed either. It goes straight to the catch block in your main method.

Answer (score 0):

1. A method returns some value if it is executed without exception or error.
2. `finally` block does not have any impact on whether return statement will be executed or not. (of course, `finally` block should not throw any further exception)
3. `catch` block determines whether that exception should be propagated further or handled within the method.

In the given example, an `ArithmeticException` is thrown from `try` block and it will be handled by respective `catch` block. As `catch` blocks again throws the same exception, given `return` statement would never execute.

**In short,** `return c;` is never executed in above program and variable `c` will be deleted as any other local variable.